# Googlebots request types

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, 404, http-headers, soft-404

Does Google's bot send HEAD requests as well as GET requests?

I wondering about this because I'm running a Tornado application that does not support HEAD request and I have a lot of 404 errors in Google Search Console.

To verify that the Tornado application is not accepting HEAD requests I do:

```
curl -I example.com/this-url-exists

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 08:49:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 7520
Connection: close
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Server: TornadoServer/4.2.1
```

I suspect that the Googlebots are doing the same for some of the crawling.

Can this be right?

Comment: See the [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2). *The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET*. Whether or not GoogleBot makes HEAD requests is somewhat beside the point, your server is violating the rules of HTTP and is broken.

Comment: yes agree, we will fix that

Comment: check this answer too https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55246/33802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Googlebot does not send HEAD requests - at least not with respect to crawling and indexing a website.

My access logs from January and February 2016 show no HEAD requests from the Googlebot.

Even if Googlebot did use HEAD requests I would be very surprised if these resulted in a 404 error in Google Search Console. Google should only report a 404 error on a failed GET request.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe a 404 for a HEAD request does however show up as a "Soft 404" in Search Console (I don't know...). Our logs do show *some* HEAD request, but we didn't log the user-agents so couldn't tell if it was Goolge - I will try to log those as well...

Comment: A "soft 404" is simply a response that "looks like" a 404, but isn't returning a 404 HTTP status code. (For example: accidentally returning your 404 page with a 200 OK status.) Yes, I see some HEAD requests in the logs, but none from the Googlebot. (In order to validate the Googlebot you need to check both the User-Agent and a reverse lookup on the IP address - since there are a lot of bots _pretending_ to be the Googlebot.)

Comment: aah yes, good point. i will try to do that. thank you

Comment: In fact, checking the IP addresses might be enough in this case. Only if it did resolve to Google would you need the User-Agent to confirm. If none resolve to Google then job done.

Comment: Google did used to use a HEAD request to check modification dates and conserve bandwidth. However, as you said, I have not seen a HEAD request in years. So that blows that theory!! It was the case at one point. I would advise that the IP address be checked. Also, keep in mind that it may not all be googlebot. Check the user agent carefully. A 404 can result from a HEAD request, however, how Google deals with this is up to debate since I agree that Google no longer uses HEAD requests. Kind of a catch-22 huh?? What came first? The Pterodactylus or the Pterodactylus egg? Does it even matter??